# Incorrect Y values shown on candlestick chart tooltip

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, charts, tooltip

I have hit an interesting problem where my candlestick chart is not displaying correct Y values in the tooltip. The actual chart candlestick appears correct.

An example data segment (raw chart data confirmed at runtime from Chart.Series(0).Points)

```
        XValue  42707.333333333336  Double
-       YValues {Length=4}  Double()
        (0) 0.01096 Double
        (1) 0.01081 Double
        (2) 0.01092998  Double
        (3) 0.01092631  Double
```

My tooltip is set in Chart.Series(0).Tooltip and has the following format :

```
#VALX{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}
High : #VAL{N8}
Low: #VALY1{N8}
Open : #VALY2{N8}
Close : #VALY3{N8}
```

And this is the incorrect tooltip displayed:
[Candlestick tooltip problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6z24.jpg)

For the record, is shows :

```
03/12/16 08:00:00
High : 0.01096000
Low : 0.01096000
Open : 0.01081000
Close : 0.01092998
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here?

(Visual Studio Express 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Blindingly obvious really. The tooltip should be set to :

```
#VALX{dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss}
High : #VALY1
Low: #VALY2
Open : #VALY3
Close : #VALY4
```

However ! The incorrect values were automatically created from Visual Studios String Keywords Editor (the ... selection box by the tooltip variable). From this window, selecting Insert New Keyword, then Y-Value, then Y-Value Index (from 0 through to 3) creates the following (incorrect) tooltip :

```
#VAL
#VALY1
#VALY2
#VALY3
```

Silly me for expecting VS to give me the correct keywords. This appears to be a bug in Visual Studio 2013.